# How to install mkvirtualenvwrapper from pip which is not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pip, virtualenv

I tried to install `virtalenvwrapper` but it failed. I have no idea what to do

```
C:\Users\Vimal Rajan>pip install virtualenvwrapper
Collecting virtualenvwrapper
  Downloading virtualenvwrapper-4.8.4.tar.gz (334 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 334 kB 1.3 MB/s
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\vimal rajan\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Vimal Rajan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3nh4gw0r\\virtualenvwrapper\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Vimal Rajan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3nh4gw0r\\virtualenvwrapper\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Vimal Rajan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-7pa4p02r'
         cwd: C:\Users\Vimal Rajan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3nh4gw0r\virtualenvwrapper\
    Complete output (3 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with the directory name: `Vimal Rajan`.

I think the error refers to the space character between `Vimal Rajan`

If the directory name is similar to the `Vimal_Rajan`, `VimalRajan` or etc, the problem is solved.

If you don't want to change your directory name `Vimal Rajan`, then you can use C:\ directory for `virtualenvwrapper`.

Comment: Thank you, man. I changed the folder name and its working.